# Passing data from some TextFields in one ViewController to a TextView in another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, viewcontroller

I am very new to iOS. I am having some difficulty with a project I am working on for iOS. I believe that this problem should have a simple solution, but I have spent hours looking at tutorials and other submissions on this website, but so far nothing has worked.

My issue is that I have 5 TextFields in ViewControllerS, and I want to take the data from those TextFields, and combine them in a TextView in ViewControllerView. Here is my code.

ViewControllerS.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewControllerS : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtfDay;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtfMonth;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtfName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtfStart;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtfEnd;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnFinish;

@end
```

ViewControllerS.m:

```
#import "ViewControllerS.h"

@interface ViewControllerS ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerS

@synthesize txtfDay;
@synthesize txtfMonth;
@synthesize txtfName;
@synthesize txtfStart;
@synthesize txtfEnd;
@synthesize btnFinish;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

}


@end
```

ViewControllerView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewControllerView : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtViewFinal;

@end
```

ViewControllerView.m:

```
#import "ViewControllerView.h"

@interface ViewControllerView ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerView

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}


#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

}

@end
```

Well, as you can see, this is basically just the skeleton of my program. I have made so many changes to this code as I followed tutorials, tried ideas from here, and listened to what my classmates had to say. Nothing has worked so far, but I know it's a simple fix. I am liking the use of NSUserDefaults, but if anyone has any other ideas, I will try them as well. Again, I'm just trying to figure out how to pass data from one ViewController to another with TextFields and a TextView.

I do not need directions for all 5, but rather just 1. I can figure out the formatting and the other 4 if I just get a nudge in the right direction.

THANK YOU FOR ANY ASSISTANCE I MAY RECEIVE! I really do enjoy programming with Xcode, but it's been very frustrating too. Thanks!

Comment: Have you got solution ?

Comment: @Andrew you can use .Plist or you can directly use forward data transformation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because at create point, your ViewControllerView instance still have not loaded UI components, so even if you pass it directly to the textView, it will be simply ignored at this point.

Create a dictionary at ViewControllerView.h to pass data from ViewControllerS like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *dicTextData;
```

and set the data into it. After doing this, just load this data from within your ViewControllerView's `-(void)viewDidLoad` and voila !

**Update**

**ViewControllerS.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ViewControllerView"]) {

        ViewControllerView *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
        destination.dicTextData = @{@"day":self.txtfDay.text,
                                    @"Month":self.txtfMonth.text,
                                    @"Name":self.txtfName.text}; //and so on...
    }
}
```

**ViewControllerView.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.txtViewFinal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My name is %@", [self.dicTextData objectForKey:@"Name"]];
    //and so on... 
}
```

Note that I did't use all fields on my example, but I'm sure you got the point. Good coding!

Comment: How do I set the data into the NSDictionary and what is the format for loading the data into the ViewControllerView.m's viewDidLoad? I had tried but I literally have no experience with Objective-C haha. Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: I told you NSDictionary because it can be used to multi-purposes, but you can use a NSString if you prefere to ... I'll update my answer to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ViewControllerView"]){
      ViewControllerView *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
      destination.finalText = self.txtfDay.text;
}
```

Please make sure you set the identifier of the segue correctly.

**Edit:**

Thanks @rmaddy point out the problem:

For uncoupling purpose, it would be a better way to store the data that you will pass with a property and let the view controller handle that data. In this case let's say there is a `NSString` type property called `finalText`. The `prepareForSegue` method stored the data and now you can handle this data freely.

Comment: Please do not follow this approach. One view controller should not have access to the controls of another view controller. Pass the data from one view controller to the other. Let the second view controller do what it needs with the data.

Comment: @rmaddy So, is it a good way to store the data with a property and let the second view controller to handle that data?

Comment: Exactly, much like the other answer states.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I just have a few questions. 1, where would I put the code you suggested? Do I put it in ViewControllerView.m or ViewControllerS.m? 2.  Do I have to do anything else besides put the code there? I tried it and I received an error saying that it could not find txtfDay when I put it in ViewControllerView.m. I imported ViewControllerS.h but I feel like that's the wrong approach. Sorry for the questions, I am *extremely* new to Xcode and I have only been programming for a couple of semesters, and barely at all with Xcode. Thank you!

Comment: 1. `ViewControllerS.m` 2.Likes the `1`, you need to put it in `ViewControllerS.m` because just as the method `prepareForSegue` say, this method is used for preparing the data before switching view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways for doing this.An alternative way is to use AppDelegate object.Follow the steps-

1. Write this line in AppDelegate.h file-

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *combinedText;
   ```
2. Import the AppDelegate file in your ViewControllerViewS.m file.Such as-

   ```
   #import "AppDelegate.h"
   ```
3. Write the line in viewDidLoad of ViewControllerViewS.m -

   ```
   appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   ```
4. Now write the line in the body of the btnFinish button-

   ```
   appDelegate.combinedText=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fDay:%@,fMonth:%@,fName:%@,fStart:%@,fEnd:%@", 
   self.txtfDay.text, self.txtfMonth.text, self.txtfName.text, self.txtfStart.text, self.txtfEnd.text];
   ```
5. Now in destination ViewController.m file repeat step 2 and 3.
6. Now assign the combined text value to the textView.Like-

   ```
    UITextView *textView=[[UITextView alloc]init];
    textView.text=appDelegate.combinedText;
   ```

Let me know if it works for you.Thank you.

Comment: No, do not use the app delegate for this. Simply pass the data directly from one view controller to another. It's a really bad idea to add random properties to the app delegate. It's not meant to be a bucket for arbitrary bits of data.